# Installing ghc cabal libraries on OSX 10.11 El Capitan, gcc permission denied error

Tags: gcc, ghc, cabal

When installing cabal packages on OSX 10.11 El Capitan, I get a permission error even though I am using an administrator account.

`cabal: /usr/bin/gcc: permission denied`

Changing it with chmod command to +rw or adding my account to root group doesn't fix the permission error. I'm able to run `gcc --version` just fine.

Answer (score 2):

After much searching and scouring through the interwebs, I stumbled upon a discussion over at Cabal issue tracker. Someone's [answer](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2653) mentioned the rootless feature with El Capitan causing problems.

Here's how to turn off the rootless feature.

1. Restart your machine. Press cmd+R until you see the apple logo
2. Open the terminal, by going to *Utilities > Terminal*
3. Type in `csrutil disable; reboot` and hit return
4. Wait for your osx to reboot itself and then proceed with continuing your cabal installation(s).

---

Reference:

- [Cabal Issue #2653](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2653) - `ar` permission errors on OS X 10.11 `El Capitan` with GHC 7.8.4
- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11) - How do I turn off the rootless in OS X El Capitan 10.11?
- [OSX Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/) - How to Disable System Integrity Protection (rootless) in OS X El Capitan